# Get the regex match and the rest (none-match) from Python's re module

Tags: python, python-re

Does the `re` module of Python3 offer an in-build way to get the match and the rest (none-match) back?

Here is a simple example:

```py
>>> import re
>>> p = r'\d'
>>> s = '1a'
>>> re.findall(p, s)
['1']
```

The result I want is something like `['1', 'a']` or `[['1'], ['a']]` or something else where I can differentiate between *match* and *rest*.

Of course can subtract the resulting (matching) string from the original one to get the rest. But is there an in build way for this?

I do not set the `regex` tag here because the question is less related to RegEx itself but more to a feature of a Python package.

Comment: Is the part you're trying to match always in the front (in the example yes, but you've asked a general question), and do you mean by _rest_ only the part _after_ the match (and not a potential part _before_ it)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possible solution is the following:

```
import re

string = '1a'
re_pattern = r'^(\d+)(.*)'

result = re.findall(re_pattern, string)
print(result)
```

Returns list of tuples

```
[('1', 'a')]
```

or if you like to return list of str items

```
result = [item for t in re.findall(re_pattern, string) for item in t]
print(result)
```

Returns

```
['1', 'a']
```

Explanations to the code:

- `re_pattern = r'(\d+)(.*)'` is looking for two groups: 1st group `(\d+)` means digits one or more, 2nd group `(.*)` means the rest of the string.
- `re.findall(re_pattern, string)` returns list of tuple like `[('1', 'a')]`
- list comprehension converts list of tuples to list of string items

Comment: This works but I do not understand why. You modified the pattern for this, correct? Can you explain what happens here and possible link to the corrosponding regex docu. **EDIT**: Fits perfect to my needs!

Answer (score 4):

You can match everything and create groups to "split" between the important part from the rest:

```
>>> import re
>>> p = r'(\d+)(.*)'
>>> s = '12a\n34b\ncde'
>>> re.findall(p, s)
[('12', 'a'), ('34', 'b')]
```

[re.findall documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall)

Comment: Isn't that more or less identical with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71589548/14311263) answer?

Comment: Thank you. It's similar, but it wasn't here when I checked the question and started to write an answer. I can see that both answers were posted with a short time of difference. I'll leave my answer here since it's conciser and has an example with more 'lines' of data - also I wanted to exemplify that the regex from the author's question will miss lines that don't have digits.

Answer (score 2):

No, the match does not show the data that was cut off by itself.

The Match object that a regex gives you contains information about where data was found, you could extract it with that

```
import re
p = r'\d(?<=)'
s = '1a'
match = next(re.finditer(p, s))
# >>> match
# <re.Match object; span=(0, 1), match='1'>

head = match.string[:match.start()]  # ""
tail = match.string[match.end():]  # "a"
```

Note that `re.findall` doesn't give you `Match`-objects, you'll need another function that does that, like `re.finditer`. I'm using `next()` here because it returns an iterator instead of a list, you'd usually cast it to a list or loop over it.

---

Another option would be to make these groups in your pattern directly.

If you're interested in both, before and after the match:

```
import re
p = r'(^.*?)(\d)(.*$)'
s = '1a'
re.findall(p, s)
# [('', '1', 'a')]
```

But this will not give you multiple results results in the same string, as they are overlapping and you can't have variable-with lookbehinds in the builtin `re` library.

If you're only interested in the string after the match, then you can do that

```
import re
p = r'(\d)(?=(.*))'
s = '1a'
re.findall(p, s)
# [('1', 'a')]
s = '1a2b'
re.findall(p, s)
# [('1', 'a2b'), ('2', 'b')]
```

Comment: Please fit your answer code to my MWE. That is why I created an MWE. And this does not answer my question because the split is down by the user itself not by the `re` package.

Comment: I still don't fully understand the question's intention, so I might be wrong, but I think this is the best answer: (1) The `match.start()`/`stop()` is the best `re`-mechanic to capture _all_ the non-match parts of the string. (2) The use of the non-consuming lookahead is superior to the simpler solutions (depending on the use case a `re.DOTALL` flag might be helpful ... or not). +1